# how can i required class on function with dynamic condition PHP

Tags: php

how can i required class on function with dynamic condition PHP

file AuthenNew.php

```
   function login($user , $pass){
    new login logic 
} enter code here
```

file AuthenLegcy.php

```
   function login($user , $pass){
    legacyy login logic 
}
```

file AuthenSelector.php

```
$config == 1;
if($config == 1){
required (AuthenNew.php)
}else{
required (AuthenLegacy.php)
}
```

file A.php

```
required (AuthenSelector.php)
Login = new Login('user','pass')
```

Comment: Apart from some minor typos, what is the problem you're encountering, or the question you have? Perhaps you need to explain when you want to use which implementation of the `login()` function?

Comment: `required (AuthenNew.php)` - that does not look like valid PHP code

Answer (score 2):

Lots of different ways to do this, but the simplest is probably to name the functions differently so that they do not conflict, and then always define both:

```php
function login($user, $pass) { ... }

function loginLegacy($user, $pass) { ... }

if ($config == 1) {
    login($user, $pass);
} else {
    loginLegacy($user, $pass);
}
```

In an object-oriented context, you'd probably want to use the [Strategy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern). First define an interface that both objects would implement:

```php
interface LoginInterface {
    public function login($user, $pass);
}
```

Then define the old and new objects so that they both implement this common interface:

```php
class Login implements LoginInterface {
    public function login($user, $pass) {
        ...
    }
}

class LoginLegacy implements LoginInterface {
    public function login($user, $pass) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Now you can perform the same action with an instance of either object:

```php
if ($config == 1) {
    $loginAdapter = new Login();
} else {
    $loginAdapter = new LoginLegacy();
}
$loginAdapter->login($user, $pass);
```